# Keep getting this error: sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mysql.pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have looked through all the questions with the same error and none have helped me resolve this issue. Here is the code:

```
import sqlalchemy
import pymysql
import sqlalchemy as db
 
def main():
    # get sqlalchemy and pymysql used libraries version
    print("sqlalchemy: {}".format(sqlalchemy.__version__))
    print("pymysql: {}".format(pymysql.__version__))
                    
    # get engine object using pymysql driver for mysql
    engine = db.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://username:password@localhost/movie")
                    
    # get connection object
    connection = engine.connect()
                    
    # get meta data object
    meta_data = db.MetaData()
                    
    # set actor creation script table
    actor = db.Table(
   "actor", meta_data,
   db.Column("id", db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True,nullable=False),
   db.Column("first_name", db.String(50), nullable=False),
   db.Column("last_name", db.String(50), nullable=False),
   db.Column("age", db.Integer, nullable=False),
   db.Column("date_of_birth", db.Date, nullable=False),
   db.Column("active", db.Boolean, nullable=False))
                    
    # create actor table and stores the information in metadata
    meta_data.create_all(engine)
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

and the error keeps coming back as "sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:mysql.pymysql" so I'm not really sure what I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you `pip install pymysql` in the environment in which you are running your code?

Comment: I did ```conda install pymysql ```

Comment: Does the print pymysql.__version__ line print anything?  It seems unlikely that that line can succeed and the engine creation line fail.

Comment: It does which is what confuses me. It prints this and then the error:
```sqlalchemy: 1.4.22
pymysql: 1.0.2```